# LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to do Navigation drawer options.

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
             android:id="@+id/sendnewmessages"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="30dp"
             android:background="@drawable/nothere"
             android:gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
             android:shadowDx="1"
             android:shadowDy="1"
             android:shadowRadius="1"
             android:text="Send New Messages"
             android:textAlignment="center"
             android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        <EditText
             android:id="@+id/searchmessage"
             android:layout_height="40dp"
             android:layout_width="200dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:hint="Search Messages"/>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>
        <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#111"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

If I remove `Linearlayout` there is no error. This button appears behind `listview`, `edittext` appears in the middle of screen. The problem is that the objects are not aligned. Is there a way align view objects in `DrawerLayout`?

If I don't remove `linearlayout` I get this error:

```
LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
```

stacktrace:

> > E/AndroidRuntime(3454): FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.brilliant.bridge, PID: 3454 java.lang.ClassCastException:
> >     android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to
> >     android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams at
> >     android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerView(DrawerLayout.java:910)
> >     at
> >     android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(DrawerLayout.java:1156)
> >     at
> >     com.brilliant.bridge.AdminMessages.onPrepareOptionsMenu(AdminMessages.java:220)
> >     at android.app.Activity.onPreparePanel(Activity.java:2556) at
> >     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:464)
> >     at
> >     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:800)
> >     at
> >     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:221)
> >     at
> >     android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
> >     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574) at
> >     android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543) at
> >     android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
> >     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) at
> >     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
> >     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
> >     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
> >     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) at
> >     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question, remove all unnecessary code, leave only the relevant parts, and indicate the line numbers.

Comment: just gives error LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams program no indicate line on code

Comment: please provide the full stacktrace

Comment: Is `AdminMessages` your class? If so please post the onPrepareOptionsMenu code.

Comment: posted onPrepareOptionsMenu

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assign an  ID to your LinearLayout in xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/DrawerLinear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- YOUR LISTVIEW IS HERE -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in you java class, Cast this LinearLayout:

```
private LinearLayout    DrawerLinear;
```

In OnCreate you should do this:

```
DrawerLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLinear);
```

And in your onPrepareOptionMenu, put this:

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(DrawerLinear);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

it should solve your problem.

Comment: kindly correct the little but difficult to notice error "findviewbyid" to "findViewById"